# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Master Layout Model Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, model-view-controller, layout, model

I have a master layout in ASP.NET Core 2.2 project which uses a Model (Like other views) to create the whole website unique design, each of my views uses different Model but all of them should load in a single Layout file.
How can I pass different Models to different Views while my Layout expects a single Model?

**I don't want to create tons of Layout files for each views group**

for visualize:

Product.cshtml (Product Model)==> _Layout.cshtml (Product Model)

Category.cshtml (Category Model)==> _Layout.cshtml (Category Model)

But _Layout.cshtml expects only one Model

Comment: The only way a view and its layout can have different models, is if the view's model is a descendant of the layout's model.

Comment: How can I pass 2 different Models in IActionResult return view?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display 2 model in 1 view right ?

You can apply MVVM pattern in this scenario.

Here is example:

I will define 3 class in Model folder

```
public class Post 
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public string Content {get;set;}
   public string UserId {get;set;}
}

public class Comment 
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Content {get;set;}
  public string PostId {get;set;}
}

// this will hold data for 2 class above
public class PostVM 
{
  public Post Post {get;set}
  public Comment Comment {get;set}
}
```

Then in my controller I will query to db to get data for post and comment like this

```
public IActionResult PostDetail(string postId)
{
  var post = _postRepository.GetPostById(postId);
  var comment = _commentRepository.GetCommentByPostId(postId);
  // MVVM model return to the view
  var vM = new PostVM 
  {
    Post = post,
    Comment = comment
  }
}
```

Finally in my view

```
@model PostVM

<div> @model.Post.Content </div>
@foreach(var comment in @model.Comment)
{
  <div> @comment.Content</div>
}
```

Please adjust accordingly with your code. If you have any problem please let me know.

Cheers

Comment: No, each view requires its own ViewModel, but my Layout expects a specific ViewModel .. how can I return a ViewModel to feed both View and Layout?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to have _Layout.cshtml to take two different models.

The best you could do is create a base model, such as

```
   public class LayoutModel
   {
     public string LayoutFieldA { get; set; }
   }
```

Then your page models can inherit the base model, like below

```
   public class ProductModel : LayoutModel
   {
     public string ProductFieldA { get; set; }
   }


   public class CategoryModel : LayoutModel
   {
     public string CategoryFieldA { get; set; }
   }
```